# Using PyQGiS in custom application gives import qgis.core error

Tags: pyqgis

I'm using windows 7 and/or 8 64 bit with QGiS 2.01.  I'm wanting to us the pyQGiS tools in a custom python application outside of the QGiS environment (i.e by running a python executable located in C:/Python27.

To do this I have been following the instructions posted at http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html

For the first step (to remove the error "ImportError: No module named qgis.core") i set my pythonpath to "C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\python"

As expected I now get an error:
File "C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\python\qgis__init__.py", line 26, in 
    import sip
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

The instructions say to add "the directories where the QGIS libraries reside".  I have tried adding a number of paths, with no success.  I also cannot locate the sip.dll file anywhere within the C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour directory.

Does anyone know which paths I need to set?